# eventReactive reacting to all input values

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I don't seem to understand reactivity. I thought that my since I defined myPlot using eventReactive, it would only update the plot when the actionButton was clicked on.  However, it updates for all reactive values.

Then, I tried wrapping the calls to input$abscissa and input$ordinate inside the eventReactive with isolate, but that caused the plot to never update (except the axis labels).

Here's a reprex. Press the "Plot" button to create the plot. If you change one of the principal components, the plot will update. How do I stop that?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

cmat <- 
  data.frame(
    matrix(
      c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 
        19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 
        47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 
        79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 
        109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 
        151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 
        191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227
      ), 
      nrow = 7
    )
  )
names(cmat) <- paste0(rep("V",7),1:7)

numPC <- dim(cmat)[[2]]-2

PC_choices <- paste0(rep("V",numPC),1:(numPC))

ordinals <- c('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth',
              'Sixth', 'Seventh', 'Eighth', 'Ninth', 'Tenth')

myPCs <- paste0(ordinals[1:min(numPC,10)],
                rep(" Principal Component", min(numPC,10)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(
        inputId = "refresh",
        label = "Plot"
      ),
      hr(),
      h5("Choose the Principal Components"),
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "abscissa",
        label = "Abscissa",
        choices = myPCs
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = "yAxis"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(
        outputId = "pcplot"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$yAxis <- renderUI({
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "ordinate",
      label = "Ordinate",
      choices = myPCs[-1*which(myPCs==input$abscissa)]
    )
  })

  myPlot <- eventReactive(input$refresh,{
      cmat %>% 
      ggplot(
        aes(
          x = .[,which(myPCs==input$abscissa)],
          y = .[,which(myPCs==input$ordinate)],
          fill = V6
        )
      ) +
      geom_point(shape = 21, color = "black", size = 4) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = median(cmat[,which(myPCs==input$abscissa)]), 
                 linetype = "dashed", 
                 size = 1, 
                 color = "yellow") +
      geom_hline(yintercept = median(cmat[,which(myPCs==input$ordinate)]), 
                 linetype = "dashed", 
                 size = 1, 
                 color = "yellow") +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("white", "cyan", "blue", "black")) +
      labs(
        title = "PCPLOT",
        x = input$abscissa,
        y = input$ordinate,
        fill = "Response"
      ) +
      theme_bw()
  })

  output$pcplot <- renderPlot({
    myPlot()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `aes()` attributes are lazily evaluated. You need to use some meta-programming to actually insert the value of the input at the time the code is ran, not at the time it is drawn. Use

```
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = .[,which(myPCs==!!(input$abscissa))],
      y = .[,which(myPCs==!!(input$ordinate))],
      fill = V6
    )
  )
```

Which will insert the value of `input$abscissa` into the `aes()` rather than the expression `input$abscissa`. Note that you don't have to do this for the `xintercept=` or `yintercept=` values because those are outside an `aes()`.

Comment: Your solution works, but could you please help me understand why. I thought that all R functions are evaluated lazily. Why does "aes" require this double-bang operator? When I make the plot, then change the principal component on the abscissa, that invalidates input$abscissa, but why does it redraw the plot? Shouldn't myPlot() only rerun its block of code when input$refresh invalidates?

Comment: The important thing to realize is that the code in the `eventReactive` is not re-run. There are two steps to making a ggplot. First is constructing the object it self which is what your code does. The second is actually rendering the plot which happens when the object is print()-ed. So in the original case, the object wasn't changed, but when the object was rendered there was now different information in the values used in `aes()` so the picture was different.

Comment: But when renderPlot first calls myPlot, it runs the code in myPlot, which creates the ggplot object, and passes that to plotOutput to be displayed in my browser. THEN, when I change the value of input$abscissa, why does the ggplot object change? Are you saying that the ggplot object, rather than containing the necessary values from cmat, refers to addresses in cmat, and that those addresses have the reactive values input$abscissa and input$ordinate, so that renderPlot redraws the plot every time those addresses change? Is there some way to make the renderPlot only react to input$refresh?

Comment: When you have `input$` in your `aes()`, then `renderPlot` still sees those as a dependency. Basically what you are doing in the `eventReactive` isn't isolating those values because you are maintaining un-evaluated expressions of those values in your object. The problem is fundamentally using ggplot incorrectly; it's not a problem with `renderPlot`. What I've done in my answer shows you how to properly evaluate those values so your `myPlot` object is no longer dependent on the input. I don't know how else to explain this to you, sorry.